# Statistics of Columns with Data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a 30 tables with roughly 2600 columns within them. I am looking for a query that counts how many columns have data, so....null = no data and not null = data.

I started with...

`SUM(CASE WHEN mycolumn is null THEN 1 else 0 END)` but doing this, I would have to create 2600 case statements...is there an easier way of doing this?

Comment: 30 databases or tables ?

Comment: 30 tables - sorry about that!